# CoffeeScript and MongoDB unable to find object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

Folks,
  Not able to find documents that do in fact exist on the local mongo instance:

```
collection = db.collection('myCollection')
console.log "looking for id",accountId

collection.find
    _id: "52d9a0dec78792f877afa0a1"
, (err, result) ->
    if err or not result
        console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
        callback 'find did not work: #{err}'
    else
        console.log result
        result.nextObject (account) ->
            console.log account
```

output:

```
Listening on 3000...
Account Name undefined
Account Balance undefined
Account Id undefined
something
looking for id 52d9a0dec78792f877afa0a1
{ toArray: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  next: [Function],
  nextObject: [Function],
  setReadPreference: [Function],
  batchSize: [Function],
  count: [Function],
  stream: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  explain: [Function],
  isClosed: [Function],
  rewind: [Function],
  limit: [Function],
  skip: [Function],
  hint: [Function],
  maxTimeMS: [Function],
  sort: [Function],
  fields: [Function] }
null
```

Comment: If your doc's `_id` is an ObjectID then you need to create one from the id string before passing it to `find`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK not sure... here is what the Document looks like https://gist.github.com/vasiliyb/8546795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject):

> #### nextObject
>
> Gets the next document from the cursor.
>
> nextObject(callback)
> Arguments: callback (function) this will be called after executing this method. **The first parameter will contain an error object** on error while **the second parameter will contain a document from the returned result** or null if there are no more results.

From [github readme](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#data-types):

```
var idString = '4e4e1638c85e808431000003';  
collection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID(idString)}, console.log)  // ok  
collection.findOne({_id: idString}, console.log)  // wrong! callback gets undefined
```

---

#### Solution

- Before querying and **`_id`** you should convert it to an **`ObjectID`**.
- In node.js callbacks, conventionally, the first argument is the an error object.

So you should write it like so:

```
collection.find
    {_id: db.ObjectID("52d9a0dec78792f877afa0a1")}
, (err, result) ->
    if err or not result
        console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
        callback 'find did not work: #{err}'
    else
        console.log result
        result.nextObject (err, account) ->
            console.log account
```

#### I think it is better to use `findOne`:

```
collection.findOne {_id: db.ObjectID("52d9a0dec78792f877afa0a1")}, (err, result) ->
  if err or not result
    console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
    callback 'find did not work: #{err}'
  else
    console.log result
    callback 'did work'
```

Comment: The OP does seem to know `result` is a cursor as they're calling `nextObject` on it.

Comment: @IlanFrumer unfortunately, i get `TypeError: Object  has no method 'toArray'`

Answer (score 1):

Your doc's `_id` is an `ObjectID` so you need to convert the id string to the right type before passing it to `find`:

```
collection.find
    _id: mongodb.ObjectID "52d9a0dec78792f877afa0a1"
, (err, result) ->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = collection.find
    _id: mongodb.ObjectID accountId
cursor.toArray (err, result) ->
            if err or not result
                console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
                callback 'find did not work: #{err}'
            else
                console.log result
                #result.toArray (account) ->
                #    console.log "Account is ", account
                callback null, result
```